# How to add cookie in ChromiumWebBrowser browser for WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, chromium, cefsharp

How i can add cookie to ChromiumWebBrowser before navigating to a URL.

I have a URL which I want to navigate, however I would like to add authToken cookie before navigating to avoid going to Login page.

Please suggest

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_Cef_GetGlobalCookieManager.htm
http://cefsharp.github.io/api/51.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_ICookieManager_SetCookieAsync.htm

Search the `GitHub project` issue tracker for examples (there should be some).

Comment: i did this long back. you can add coockies of websites in cef settings. try checking cef settings.

Answer (score 1):

I have used below code to add authentication Token cookie before navigating to specific URL and avoid going to Login page.

```
var mngr = Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager();
Cookie Ac = new Cookie();
Ac.HttpOnly = true;
Ac.Name = ".ASPXAUTH";
Ac.Value = "";
mngr.SetCookieAsync(matrixUrl.ToString(), Ac);
```